# Difference between passing by reference or by value a container of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, containers

Generally, in C++, I am aware of the differences between parsing by value, or by reference or a pointer, but I am confused when passing containers.

My question is what is the difference of passing by reference or by value a container of pointers.
And also what is the difference of passing by reference a container of non pointers and passing by value a container of pointers.

More specifically in both questions below, what happens if 'func()' changes the value of a 'myClass' argument:

1. what's the difference between:

   ```
   void func(list<myClass*> myList);
   ```

   and

   ```
   void func(list<myClass*> &myList);
   ```
2. what's the difference between:

   ```
   void func(list<myClass> &myList);
   ```

   and

   ```
   void func(list<myClass*> myList);
   ```

EDIT:
If you want the changes of the calling function to be reflected to the original object which options do you have and what's the difference of them?
As far as I understand you have these options:
Either

```
 void func(list<myClass*>& myList);
```

or

```
 void func(list<myClass>& myList);
```

Comment: Assuming `<*myClass>` is supposed to be `<myClass*>`. 1 Copies a list of pointers 2. Passes a reference to a list of pointers, it's generally cheaper than the first, but accessing it may be slightly more expensive than accessing a copy. 3. The sort of signature you usually want to aim for, passes a list of objects by reference (no copying) 4. same as 1.

Comment: @George Sorry, I asked for the differences between them, not a verbal declaration..

Answer (score 2):

```
void func(list<*myClass> myList);
```

This call copies the argument and create a new list. Any modification on that copy will not be reflected on the calling argument.

```
void func(list<*myClass>& myList);
```

This call doesn't copy the argument. Any modification to the list will be reflected to the original list (because it is using it), as the argument reference this list.

```
void func(const list<*myClass>& myList);
```

In general, people use `const list<*myClass>&` to avoid the copy and forbid modifications.

```
void func(list<myClass>* myList);
```

I assume this was the question you wanted to ask instead of `list<*myClass>`. So this passes a pointer instead of a reference. This means that `myList` may not exist, contrary to the reference that must refer to an existing object. It's often used for optional arguments.

```
void func(list<myClass> myList);
```

Apparently, I was mistaken, and this is the real comparison.

This is just another object, there is no way to convert a `list<myClass>` into a `list<*myClass>`. A list of pointers can be interesting if `myClass` is virtual, if they are managed else where.

So the difference between the two calls is basically how you handle the objects, either by value because you want the objects themselves in the list (and yes, you want to pass them by reference) or you want just a list of pointers (but you should still pass them by reference or const reference, almost never by value, except if you need a copy of the list to modify).

Comment: The first comparison is understood and thank you for it.
For the second comparison, I meant what I wrote with the pointer but I think I understood it from the first comparison you made...

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Haha thank you again but the last call is "void func(list<myClass*> myList);" (as the first one).

Also, i will now edit the question again to add something. Please check it.

Comment: The 4th doesn't have the star in them, and my last paragraph covers your edit. It all depends on your memory model.